# How can I play local video file (inbuilt my apps) in iPhone using cordova 2.5

Tags: ios, iphone, video, cordova

I want to play local video file (like .mp4) in my iPhone apps. I can play youtube video file but I need play local storage file (myVideo.mp4) in my 'www' folder. How is it possible in iPhone7 using cordova 2.5? I am using html 5 video tag but unable to launch local video on my iPhone 7 device.

Answer (score 0):

First you just put a normal video tag into your html page:

```
<video id="video" controls>
     <source src="media/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

The video physical path is "www/media/video/video.mp4". Next ensure you have allowed video playback in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
```

That's should be all.