# Load and play local video file included with the cordova app in iframe page loaded from an external url

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

This is included in my cordova app `index.html` and it successfully loads the external page in an iframe.

```
    <div>
    <iframe width="360" height="715" src="http://192.168.0.1/" target="_parent"/></iframe>
    </div>
```

The iframe page includes the following html to load the video:

```
    <video id="source" width="100%" height="100%">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Id like to specify a local video file that is bundled with the app and be able to play it from the external page once the page is loaded in the iframe.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583613/how-can-i-play-local-video-file-inbuilt-my-apps-in-iphone-using-cordova-2-5

Comment: @SimpleCTO thanks for the link, what they are trying to do is play a local video in the local index.html file. I'm trying to play a local video in an external html file that is loaded as an iframe in the local index.html file